# Force user of LibGDX game to stay in the game

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx

I'm trying to make an Android app (or series of games/apps) wherein I need to force the user to stay in the game, or make it hard to leave. Here's my actual scenario: I need to make an app for a special needs child so that it's difficult for him to get out of the game or app. It's really easy for him to pull down the notification bar and get into the settings, use the home/menu/back buttons, call China, etc. just by fumbling around the screen.

I'm looking for advice for the following (related) things, and maybe some that I haven't thought of:

1. Prevent notification bar pull-down
2. Prevent menu from being used
3. Prevent home button from being used
4. Prevent back button from being used
5. Allow caregivers to change options, exit the app, etc.
6. Be responsive to incoming calls

Now, to be fair, I have done some research, but I haven't quite gotten there yet. I have an app requiring a double-tap back button to exit, and I don't display anything with the menu button. The notification bar pulls down, but is empty. I'm also using [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) fullscreen activities. Just hoping there's something else out there that I haven't run into yet.

Any advice out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 and 4 can be solved simply by using this once in your game anywhere:

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

aswell as

```
Gdx.input.setCatchMenyKey(true);
```

After these two lines in your game's lifetime, the back and menu key won't do anything unless you use them through:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)) {}
```

aswell as

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.MENU)) {}
```